Unexpected behaviour of vertical space/glue between theorems (with amsthm)
I was developing a macro to insert some material "in the background" while preserving the layout of the rest of the page.
I noticed an unexpected behaviour when the insertion point was between two amsthm theorems: there were extra vertical space added.
Then I've discovered that the same happens even when inserting space/glue or kern between theorems.
Consider a simpler situation where I would want to manually enlarge the vertical gap between two theorems.
If I insert \vspace*{...}, the result is not what I would expect: even inserting \vspace*{0pt} changes the spacing.
Here is an example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{T}
\begin{document}

%\setbox0=\vtop{

\begin{theorem}A.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}B.
\end{theorem}

\vspace*{0pt}

\begin{theorem}C.
\end{theorem}

\kern 0pt

\begin{theorem}D.
\end{theorem}

\vskip 0pt

\begin{theorem}E.
\end{theorem}

%}
%\showboxbreadth=100
%\showboxdepth=4
%\showbox0
%\box0

\end{document}

The appearance in the produced PDF:

Investigation with \showbox produced this output in the log file:
[...]
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0
.\hbox(6.86111+0.0)x345.0, glue set 308.7224fil
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 T
..\kern 0.0
..\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91473 minus 1.27904
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 1
..\kern 0.0
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 .
..\glue 5.0 plus 1.0 minus 1.0
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 A
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 .
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\glue -8.0 plus -2.0 minus -4.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0
.\glue(\baselineskip) 5.13889
.\hbox(6.86111+0.0)x345.0, glue set 309.11684fil
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 T
..\kern 0.0
..\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91473 minus 1.27904
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 2
..\kern 0.0
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 .
..\glue 5.0 plus 1.0 minus 1.0
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 B
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 .
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
.\penalty 10000
.\glue 0.0
.\glue 0.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0
.\glue(\baselineskip) 5.13889
.\hbox(6.86111+0.0)x345.0, glue set 309.00018fil
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 T
..\kern 0.0
..\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91473 minus 1.27904
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 3
..\kern 0.0
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 .
..\glue 5.0 plus 1.0 minus 1.0
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 C
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 .
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\kern 0.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0
.\glue(\baselineskip) 5.13889
.\hbox(6.86111+0.0)x345.0, glue set 308.60574fil
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 T
..\kern 0.0
..\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91473 minus 1.27904
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 4
..\kern 0.0
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 .
..\glue 5.0 plus 1.0 minus 1.0
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 D
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 .
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\glue 0.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
.\glue(\parskip) 0.0
.\glue(\baselineskip) 5.13889
.\hbox(6.86111+0.0)x345.0, glue set 309.37239fil
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 T
..\kern 0.0
..\glue 3.83331 plus 1.91473 minus 1.27904
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 5
..\kern 0.0
..\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 .
..\glue 5.0 plus 1.0 minus 1.0
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 E
..\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 .
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty -51
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
[...]

The spacing difference is due to
.\glue -8.0 plus -2.0 minus -4.0

which appears only in the first inter theorem gap and apparently serves to cancel the previous
.\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0

(In fact, experimenting with lualatex, I saw that such negative glue was cancelling the sum of \glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0 with another small amount of glue that is absent when compiling with pdflatex.)
So, I have the questions:

What are the rules for the space/glue inserted around theorem environment that explain this behaviour?

What are possible workarounds if I want to insert something between theorems without affecting the vertical distance between them?

Where does the glue value 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0 come from, or how is it computed?



Just an idea. You could write the position to the aux file and add the content to the shipout/background hook on the next run. Not sure if this would mess up the \addvspace calculation explained in egreg's answer


You could define a command that adds the requested space (effectively) before the last existing space on the list. That means that the following theorem sees the original \lastskip so adds the original amount of space and the extra space added by \addextravspace does contribute that amount of space to the page.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{T}

\NewDocumentCommand\addextravspace{m}{%
  \ifvmode
    \skip0=\lastskip
    \vskip-\skip0
    \vskip#1\relax
    \vskip\skip0
  \fi
  }
\begin{document}

%\setbox0=\vtop{

\begin{theorem}A.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}B.
\end{theorem}

\addextravspace{0pt}

\begin{theorem}C.
\end{theorem}

\addextravspace{10pt}

\begin{theorem}D.
\end{theorem}

\addextravspace{5pt}

\begin{theorem}E.
\end{theorem}

%}
%\showboxbreadth=100
%\showboxdepth=4
%\showbox0
%\box0

\end{document}


List environmenta (which theorems are a special case of) are preceded and followed by \addvspace instructions. The default is \topsep (but any length would display the same issue). We get, for two consecutive theorem statements:
<last line of the statement>
\addvspace{\topsep}
\addvspace{\topsep}
<first line of the statement>

What does \addvspace do? It basically examines the last item in the vertical list being built; if it's glue, it looks at the amount thereof and compares it to its argument, issuing glue so the final space equals the largest of the two; otherwise it emits glue as specified.
What happens in your case with \vspace*{0pt}? You get:
<last line of the statement>
\addvspace{\topsep}
\vspace*{0pt}
\addvspace{\topsep}
<first line of the statement>

The first \addvspace is not preceded by glue, so it emits \topsep glue. The second \addvspace is indeed preceded by glue, but this glue is zero, and is not the \topsep glue emitted before. Thus you get a total amount of space that's twice \topsep.
OK, now let's see what \vspace*{0pt} does: since it's called in vertical mode, it does:
\dimen@\prevdepth
\hrule \@height\z@
\nobreak
\vskip 0pt
\vskip\z@skip
\prevdepth\dimen@

Let's see the log with \showoutput:
...\penalty -51
...\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
...\rule(0.0+0.0)x*
...\penalty 10000
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0
...\penalty -51
...\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0

The penalty is due to the end of the first theorem. Next there's \topsep glue, then the rule, the penalty and the two zero skips from \vspace*{0pt}.
Here's what you get instead with no \vspace* in between:
...\penalty -51
...\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0
...\glue -8.0 plus -2.0 minus -4.0
...\penalty -51
...\glue 8.0 plus 2.0 minus 4.0

The second \addvspace emits glue that cancels the first \topsep glue, then the penalty for a rather good break point and then \topsep glue again.
With \kern0pt it's the same, because a kern is not glue.
There's no general solution, I'm afraid.
